# Laravel config/app.php on production not updated

Tags: laravel

****Updated

I've changed config/app.php file , I've added to locales new language, german and app is in production, locally my changes are ok, I can use German, but on production locale isn't working. I'm using Laravel 7.4.. . any suggestion would be great.

```
'locales' => [
        ['value' => 'en' , 'name' => 'English'],
        ['value' => 'es' , 'name' => 'Spanish'],
        ['value' => 'pt' , 'name' => 'Portuguese'],
        ['value' => 'fr' , 'name' => 'French'],
        ['value' => 'de' , 'name' => 'German']
    ],
```

***Updated

Config/app.php is now working on production, but I have a problem with command `php artisan app:trans-all` .. command should translate all models in db, locally this is working but on production this command is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you recache the configuration? `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: yes but no luck @lagbox

Comment: php artisan queue:restart ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not detected"?

Comment: @NicoHaase i;ve fixed the problem, but job command `php artisan app:trans-all` on production doesn't work, and locally yes. any ideas?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good description of your problem, so the best idea for this is: start debugging

Comment: It's better if you can share the error message too. Try below steps
1) run php artisan optimize
2) Check the .env file whether you have all the parameaters
3) Check the unprocessed or failed queue jobs `php artisan queue:failed`

Comment: thank you all. php artisan queue:restart has worked :)